# Ambiguous question: determine total length a dog on a leash can reach within a triangular garden

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles, angle

Attempting to teach my sister trig. I'm completely unsure how to approach the following question. She has learnt about the unit circle, sine and cosine laws.

I thought it was asking to determine how much the dog could reach so I modeled it as a circle enclosed in the triangle with a radius of 5m. Any advice on how to think about this question would be greatly appreciated.

I got $15.7$m by dividing the circumference of a theorized circle in half, but the answer is $15.2$m, is the top right portion of the circle being cut by the triangle $PBX$ (if it were drawn, where $XB>CB$)?

[image]

Comment: You are asked for the length of fence the dog can reach.  It is $10$ meters along $AB$ and some more along $BC$.  You should find the two points on BC that are $5$m from $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that the answer is determined using a circle of radius $5$ meters, with the center at $P$, as shown below,

[image: OP's picture of a right-angled triangle with a 5-meter circle, along with several lengths and intersection points on the triangle, added]

where $D$, $F$, $G$ and $H$ are the intersection points of the triangle with the circle. In particular, the dog can reach any of parts of the fence that are within $5$ meters of the leash's tether point at $P$, with this being those sections enclosed in the circle (i.e., the triangle lines shown in green).

Since $|PD| = |PF| = 5$, we have that $\triangle DPF$ is [isosceles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_triangle). Thus, the angle bisector of $\angle DPF$ meets $CB$ at $E$ at a right angle so, by [ASA (angle-side-angle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)#Determining_congruence), we have $\triangle PED \cong \triangle PEF$. This means $|DE|=|EF|=a$ for some $a \gt 0$. Next, since $\measuredangle PEB = 90^{\circ}$, we then have from $\triangle PEB$ that

$$\sin(41^{\circ}) = \frac{|EP|}{|PB|} = \frac{h}{6.5} \; \; \to \; \; h = 6.5\sin(41^{\circ}) \approx 4.26438\,\text{m}$$

Using the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) with $\triangle PEF$, we get

$$|PE|^2+|EF|^2=|PF|^2 \; \to \; h^2 + a^2 = 5^2 \; \to \; a = \sqrt{25 - h^2} \approx 2.6105\,\text{m}$$

As [Ross Millikan's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586602/ambiguous-question-determine-total-length-a-dog-on-a-leash-can-reach-within-a-t#comment9656509_4586602) indicates, the total dog reachable length of the fence, $L$, would be the sum of the lengths of those displayed green triangle lines, i.e., the diameter $|GH| = 10\,\text{m}$, plus $|DF| = 2a$, to get that

$$L \approx 10 + 2(2.6105) \approx 15.2\,\text{m}$$